# Mockito: using mockStatic() - how to mock instance methods on the scoped mock object

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

Here is a simple test example to show what fails and when. In short, I mock a static `now()` method of the `Instance` class but later on there is another call of this mocked instance, - `minus()` method which will return `null`:

```java
@Test
    void givenInstantMock_whenNow_thenGetFixedInstant() {
        String instantExpected = "2014-12-22T10:15:30Z";
        Clock clock = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse(instantExpected), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        Instant instant = Instant.now(clock);

        try (MockedStatic<Instant> mockedStatic = mockStatic(Instant.class)) {
            mockedStatic.when(Instant::now).thenReturn(instant);
            Instant now = Instant.now();
            assertThat(now.toString()).isEqualTo(instantExpected);

            Instant earlier2weeks = now.minus(Period.ofWeeks(2));
            assertNotNull(earlier2weeks);// FAILS as it will be null
        }
    }
```

In the real situation, a service class creates a new Instant with `Instant::now`:

```java
//in a component class
@Component
class DeletionScheduler {
...
public void findOutdatedEntries() {
  Instant limitDate = Instant.now().minus(validityGracePeriod);
        List<Entry> entriedToDelete= shareService.findOutdatedEtriees(limitDate );
...
}
```

So as you can see, even if I mock the `Instant.now()` the call to `minus` on this instance will always return NULL.

```
So the idea of the test was:

- to create an entry with a `limitDate` in the future.
- trick/mock the System clock to be in the future
- check if there are some outdated entries.

Is there any way to get around it?
```

Comment: Treat Clock as a service, inject it, and use Clock.now() or Instant.now(Clock) to get the current time. Then in tests you can inject the Clock.fixed(...) you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I updated the original comment content to give a more clear understanding.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

This is because all static method of `Instant` is returning null within the try block, the behaviour is the same as we do for instance method in instance mock.

If we debug into the `minus` call, it will finally arrive `ofEpochSecond` which will return null.

```java
    private Instant plus(long secondsToAdd, long nanosToAdd) {
        if ((secondsToAdd | nanosToAdd) == 0) {
            return this;
        }
        long epochSec = Math.addExact(seconds, secondsToAdd);
        epochSec = Math.addExact(epochSec, nanosToAdd / NANOS_PER_SECOND);
        nanosToAdd = nanosToAdd % NANOS_PER_SECOND;
        long nanoAdjustment = nanos + nanosToAdd;  // safe int+NANOS_PER_SECOND
        return ofEpochSecond(epochSec, nanoAdjustment);
    }
```

### Workaround

You can provide setting for `defaultAnswer` to call real method by default.

```java
try (MockedStatic<Instant> mockedStatic = mockStatic(Instant.class,  
     withSettings().defaultAnswer(invocation -> invocation.callRealMethod()))) {
     mockedStatic.when(Instant::now).thenReturn(instant);
     ...
}
```

### Better solution

referring to [Clock javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html)

> The primary purpose of this abstraction is to allow alternate clocks to be plugged in as and when required. Applications use an object to obtain the current time rather than a static method. This can simplify testing.

And suggested by [bowmore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1886012/bowmore), we should treat Clock as a service, and set the time as desired.

In addition, static method is global by default, hence changing(static mock) it behaviour is as error prone as changing a global variable.

Comment: Using ` withSettings().defaultAnswer(invocation -> invocation.callRealMethod()` worked fine for me. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use Mocked Construction in Mockito:**

Try block Code:

```
try (MockedConstruction<Instant> mockedConstruction = mockConstruction(Instant.class,
            (mock, context) -> {
                //this initializer will be called each time during mock creation
                when(mock::now).thenReturn(instant);
            })) {
        
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        assertThat(now.toString()).isEqualTo(instantExpected);

        Instant earlier2weeks = now.minus(Period.ofWeeks(2));
        assertNotNull(earlier2weeks);// should work now
    }
```

Above code should work as it will mock every **new construction** of the object.