# How to get the file name from .properties file in java JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, properties-file

I have 8 test cases in which each test case makes use of a different file. How do I get the specific file from the .properties file which contains the path for the file(s). Some of the test cases are as shown below:

```
@Test
    public void testIfColDataReadIsCorrect() throws FileNotFoundException{

        obj.readExcelToGetData("D:/ExcelTestFiles/testExcelWithAllColData.xlsx");
        rowObj= obj.getRowRecord();
        assertEquals(rowObj.getName(), TEST_NAME);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getId(), TEST_id);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getDate(), TEST_DATE);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getMessage(), TEST_MSG);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getPage(), TEST_PAGE);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getType(), TEST_TYPE);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getLikeCount(),TEST_LIKECOUNT);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getShareCount(), TEST_SHARECOUNT);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getCommentCount(), TEST_COMMENTCOUNT);
    }
    @Test
    public void testWhenNameColDoesNotExists() throws FileNotFoundException{
        //FacebookDataExtraction obj= new FacebookDataExtraction();
        //FacebookFields rowObj=new FacebookFields();
        obj.readExcelToGetData("D:/ExcelTestFiles/testExcelWithNoNameCol.xlsx");
        rowObj= obj.getRowRecord();
        assertEquals(rowObj.getName(), null);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getId(), TEST_id);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getDate(), TEST_DATE);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getMessage(), TEST_MSG);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getPage(), TEST_PAGE);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getType(), TEST_TYPE);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getLikeCount(),TEST_LIKECOUNT);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getShareCount(), TEST_SHARECOUNT);
        assertEquals(rowObj.getCommentCount(), TEST_COMMENTCOUNT);

    }
```

I think this is not the best practice to directly input the file path to the method `readExcelToGetData()`. After going through certain posts I found that the files can the put in `.properties` file and can be read from it. How do I get the specific file path in each test case?

Comment: The first hit for a google search on `java junit properties` revealed [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557562/does-junit-support-properties-files-for-tests)

Answer (score 2):

You can load files from the classpath via a `ClassLoader`. E.g. : `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myFiles.properties")`;
So depending on your IDE, you might put the properties file into your source- or resources folder.

Comment: Correct. I would suggest putting the test files in the test/resources folder. Putting the filename (or resource name) directly in the test method isn't a bad idea, if you ask me, because otherwise one would have to search through the properties file to find out which file failed. Which, btw, is also an argument for good test method names ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Running the JUnit test with [@Parameterized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) runner allows you to run multiple iterations of the same test with different inputs.

You can read the test parameters from whatever source you wish and use them in the parameterized test without the need to copy the test method for every input.

You'll need at least JUnit 4.11 to use `Parameterized`.